# Usar variável global no Typescript com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Estou procurando uma forma de usar variável global no typescript com NodeJS. Por exemplo no js eu posso fazer:

```
//init.js
  global.foo = "foo";
//teste.js
  var foo = global.foo;
```

Há alguma forma de fazer isso no typescript?
PS: Eu sei que não é uma boa prática, mas gostaria de aprender.

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim, mas como você mesmo falou, não é muito legal usar globals, uma forma de fazer é criando um módulo e uma interface dentro desse módulo, como esse exemplo:

Nome do arquivo: **global.d.ts** (Nome de exemplo, geralmente utilizado com esse sufixo para diretivas)

```
declare module NodeJS {
export interface Global {
    __base_path: any,
    __helpers_path: any,
    __emails_path: any,
    __config: any,

}
```

E depois é declarar no seu **tsconfig.js** esse módulo, como esse exemplo:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "baseUrl": "./",
    },
    "files": [
        "global.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Pode observar o files ali com o global.d.ts, deixando explicito esse módulo sendo importado.

Com esses dois procedimentos você garante que as globais vão funcionar com o TS, mas mesmo assim o compilador do Typescript pode reclamar de não encontrar as variáveis globais. Para resolver isso (**gambiarra**), você pode declarar uma variavel chamada globaany, com o tipo any e atribuir o globals para ela, e depois usar o globalany com as suas globais.
Vou mostrar um exemplo de código para ficar mais claro.

**Sem erro de compilação do TS**

```
const globalAny: any = global
globalAny.__basepath //return basepath
```

**Com erro de compilação do TS**

```
const basepath = global.__basepath
```